# Stored list of array using For Each loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, foreach

I want to store the "zone_check_value" to a array of string then while inserting into array i will check the array of string if the next value is repeated or have duplicate.

Example.

```
1st Example
    1st loop = zone_check_value = ZD1/01/2014
    2nd loop = zone_check_value = ZD1/01/2014
2nd Example
    1st loop = zone_check_value = ZD1/01/2014
    2nd loop = zone_check_value = ZD2/02/2014
    3rd loop = zone_check_value = ZD1/01/2014
```

Code:

```
 For Each dt As DataTable In xls.Tables
   Dim array_of_string as String() 'i want to put the value in here
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim zone_destination As String = dr(2).ToString
        Dim affected_date As String = dr(7).ToString
        Dim zone_check_value = zone_destination + affected_date
        ''''''How can i store zone_check_value in a string array?
    Next
Next
```

EDIT

What if i add select case in my loop? the array_of_string value become NULL. I need to check the value of the current value in array_of_string .

Example Code

```
 For Each dt As DataTable In xls.Tables
   Dim array_of_string as String() 'i want to put the value in here
   select Case dt.tablename
    case "Sheet1"
      For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim zone_destination As String = dr(2).ToString
        Dim affected_date As String = dr(7).ToString
        Dim zone_check_value = zone_destination + affected_date
        ''''''How can i store zone_check_value in a string array?
      Next
    case "Sheet 2"
      For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
         Dim check_value as Boolean = array_of_string.Contains(dr(0).ToString)
         'but when i got in sheet 2 the array_of_string is null
      Next
Next
```

Comment: You've tagged this question with both vb.net and vba.  Please choose one or the other.

Comment: sorry @Dan-o now i already edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `List(Of String)`.

```
For Each dt As DataTable In xls.Tables
   Dim array_of_string as List(Of String) = New List(Of String) 'i want to put the value in here
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim zone_destination As String = dr(2).ToString
        Dim affected_date As String = dr(7).ToString
        Dim zone_check_value = zone_destination & affected_date
        ''''''How can i store zone_check_value in a string array?
        array_of_string.Add(zone_check_value)
    Next
    ''' Now if you really need it in array form you can cast it via:
    ''' Dim values() As String = array_of_string.ToArray()
Next
```

You might even consider:

```
For Each dt As DataTable In xls.Tables
  Dim values As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
  dt.Rows.ForEach( Sub(item) values.Add(item(2).ToString & item(7).ToString) )
  ''' Now do something with values.
Next
```

Either way, make sure you always use the string concatenation operator <kbd>&</kbd> to concatenate strings.  The arithmetic addition operator <kbd>+</kbd> will cause you problems from time to time if you use it on strings.

Comment: can i ask again what i add select case? you can see my post can you help me to my problem

Comment: That's what your debugger is for.  Step through your code line by line and see what it's doing.